# Step-by-Step Use of Transaction Control with Custom Output File Name in Informatica

Tags: transactions, informatica

Informatica developers, it seems, have a need for a step-by-step guide to using the transaction control transformation in a mapping wherein the intended break is for various files to be created as records get output from the TC.  Taking a common need for an example, creating a new file every x number of records output, I decided to put this example together.  Before trying my hand at it myself, I really wish I had had a step-by-step guide, since it took several days to get things working.  "It shouldn't be that hard," as they say, and I agree.  So I hope this helps others.

PROBLEM: You have a mapping that needs to output a large number of records.  Your internal client wants a .csv file which you can provide easily enough, but they want to be able to import each .csv file into its own Excel worksheet.  They will do the importing, but do not want to break up the large output file manually since it's a bit past their technical skill level and there is no will to learn how to use a high-capacity file editor to open the output file and then copy and paste out each 'x' number of records with 'x' being an Excel-friendly number.  So they want the output data delivered to them already broken up into Excel-friendly .csv files, each file holding 65,000 records, which is close to Excel's row limit`*`.  How can you make sure the files are automatically broken up at 65,000-record increments, a new file with a distinct name created at each 65,000-record point?

---

`*`Earlier vers. of Excel have a limit of just over 65,500 rows per worksheet.  However more recent vers. do not.  For the sake of this example, I am assuming you work in a co. that is using an older ver. of Excel that has this record limit-per-worksheet.  (The most recent vers. of Excel allows for just over one million rows per worksheet.  See this link for more info.: https://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx )

Comment: If your OS is UNIX then this can be achieved by simple SPLIT command. Just a suggestion J.

Comment: Yes, one can use a Unix command to split the file as you suggest.  Not all Inform. ppl are Unix-savvy or some places may have a no-shell-use policy for some reason (security, etc.).  But it's a good alternative for places that permit and encourage shell use from sessions.

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:

1. First you will need to add support for a custom filename to the file target in the mapping.  Do this by editing the target file so that the special 'FileName' port is added to it.  This is done by going to the list of ports in the target and clicking the shaded "F" just above and in the upper-right corner of the target port list area.  The port 'FileName' will appear and it will have a fixed length of 255 and be shaded.  This is not editable by the user.  Save the target and check it in.  Then go back to the mapping you are working on.  Refresh the view as necessary so that the target's new 'FileName' port appears in the target port list in the mapping.
2. Add an expression transformation to your mapping and connect the ports you want to connect to it that will eventually connect to the transaction control transformation.
3. Edit the port list in the 'Ports' tab in the expression transformation to add a string variable port named 'PhysicalFileName' with a length of 255; make it the first port in the list of ports.  Its Expression value should be the first part of the filename you want to use for the output files.  For example, if I want my output files to be named in the form 'ABCReport_x.csv' where x is a number such as 1, 2, 3 (e.g.: 'ABC_Report_1.csv', 'ABC_Report_2.csv', etc.), this is the value I would use:

   ```
   'ABC_Report_'
   ```

Then add another variable type integer port named 'var_recordcount' and for the Expression value of it, indicate as follows:

```
    var_recordcount + 1
```

Next, add another variable type string port named 'var_filenumber' and for the Expression value of it, indicate as follows:

```
    IIF(MOD(var_recordcount,65000)=0, to_char((var_recordcount/65000)+1), IIF(var_filenumber='','1',var_filenumber))
```

Now add another variable type integer port named 'var_new_FN_flag' and for the Expression value of it, indicate as follows:

```
    IIF(var_prev_FN = (PhysicalFileName || var_filenumber), 0, 1)
```

(Note 'var_prev_FN' is not yet defined, but it will be as the next port, so click OK if you get a parse challenge, accepting the entered Expression value as it is.)

And then immediately after that one, add another variable type string port named 'var_prev_FN' with a length of 255 and an Expression value of:

```
    PhysicalFileName || var_filenumber
```

After that port, add another output port of type string named 'o_Physical_File_Name' with a length of 255, with an Expression value of:

```
    PhysicalFileName || var_filenumber || '.csv'
```

Finally, after that one, add another output port type integer named 'o_new_FN_flag' with an Expression value of:

```
    var_new_FN_flag
```

After these ports, the rest of the ports you want to see make it into the output files ought to be listed; notice we are taking care of the various variable manipulation, etc. at the top of the port listing and only finally listing the output ports *after* those variables are manipulated/set.  Click 'Apply' and 'OK' in the Ports tab to close the 'Edit Transformations' dialog box.

4. Add a transaction control transformation and connect all the output ports from the expression transformation in step 3 to it.  The transaction control transformation should have two ports created for managing the name of the output file: o_new_FN_flag and o_Physical_File_Name.  In the transaction control transformation's 'Transaction Control Condition' box, its Value should read:

   ```
   IIF(o_new_FN_flag = 0,TC_CONTINUE_TRANSACTION,TC_COMMIT_BEFORE)
   ```

Click 'Apply', then 'OK' to close the 'Edit Transformations' dialog box for the transaction control transformation.

5. Connect all the ports in the transaction control transformation to the file target except for the 'o_new_FN_flag' port.  The 'o_Physical_File_Name' port connects to the target's 'FileName' port and the substantive ports that you have in the transaction control transformation go to wherever they need to in the target file.

That should do it.  If you follow these directions and have a problem, feel free to post.  I'll track this post to see how it goes for others.  (Sometimes, Informatica can as we know be veryyy finicky....).  One final note: the first output file will hold 64,999 rows.  The rest will hold 65,000.  There is a way to adjust the logic so that the first file also holds 65,000 rows, but this is meant to be an example.  Adding that piece of jumping-through-hopes would only muck up an already involved example.

Comment: Adding to above: You have to use TC_COMMIT_AFTER in this case. File name port has to be created while defining Informatica Flat_File target.

Comment: Hi Navjot, I use TC_COMMIT_BEFORE and have no prob.  I also have added the FileName port after initially creating the target, though of course then mappings using it'd need to be updated to accomodate the new state it's in.  Re the commit time though, what was your experience w/it leading you to conclude that AFTER is needed in this case?

Comment: You're right BEFORE looks fine. I overthinked it. J